# RESTful WCF Service That Needs to Upload Images And Multiple Arguments

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I am in the process of developing a WCF service that needs to take in an image and 2 parameters.  One being an int type, the other a string array. So this would be easy enough if it were only 1 parameter to send up, along with the image:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadImages/{imageID}")]
public void UploadImages(int imageID, Stream image)
{                       
}
```

Now, in this scenario the image is in the body of the post. What if the consumer of the service needs to pass up a third piece of data, how does that look and work in WCF?

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingStreamed" transferMode="Streamed"></binding>
      </webHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>
    <services> 
      <service name="ImageService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="MyWebHttpBehavior"  name="ImageServiceWebBinding" contract=IImageService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>      
      <endpointBehaviors>          
        <behavior name="MyWebHttpBehavior">
          <customWebHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="customWebHttp" type="CustomHttpBehaviorExtensionElement, ImageUploader" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the additional parameters in the URI as well, like in the example below. Or you can pass them as HTTP headers and fetch them using the `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers` property.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadImages/{fileName}?imageId={imageID}")]
public void UploadImages(int imageID, string fileName, Stream image)
{                       
}
```

**Update**

Even if the parameter type is an array, you can also pass it in the query string - but you'll need to provide a `QueryStringConverter` which can decode that type. The example below shows that.

```
public class StackOverflow_6905108
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadImages/{fileName}?array={array}")]
        public void UploadImages(int[] array, string fileName, Stream image)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Array:");
            foreach (var item in array) Console.Write("{0} ", item);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    public static void SendPost(string uri, string contentType, string body)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = contentType;
        Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] reqBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
        reqStream.Write(reqBytes, 0, reqBytes.Length);
        reqStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse resp;
        try
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
        foreach (string headerName in resp.Headers.AllKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", headerName, resp.Headers[headerName]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(respStream).ReadToEnd());

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    class MyQueryStringConverter : QueryStringConverter
    {
        QueryStringConverter originalConverter;
        public MyQueryStringConverter(QueryStringConverter originalConverter)
        {
            this.originalConverter = originalConverter;
        }
        public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
        {
            return type == typeof(int[]) || base.CanConvert(type);
        }
        public override object ConvertStringToValue(string parameter, Type parameterType)
        {
            if (parameterType == typeof(int[]))
            {
                return parameter.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ConvertStringToValue(parameter, parameterType);
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
    {
        protected override QueryStringConverter GetQueryStringConverter(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            return new MyQueryStringConverter(base.GetQueryStringConverter(operationDescription));
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Service), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new MyWebHttpBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        SendPost(baseAddress + "/UploadImages/a.txt?array=1,2,3,4", "application/octet-stream", "The file contents");

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response carlosfigueira.  I guess I will have to fall to HTTP headers, since the 3rd piece of data that needs to go up is an array.

Comment: As I've added in my updated answer, you can use query string parameters for arrays as well.

Comment: For request in operation UploadImages to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream.

Comment: There was an old bug in which if you enable Metadata for the service, you may see this issue. It's actually harmless, you should still be able to call the UploadImages method without any problems.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. It worked. I'm going to try and run a Web Client version now.

Comment: I am having all sorts of issues getting this to work in IIS.1st off,the UploadImages/{fileName}?array={array} URI scheme is gives me a 404,unless I put in the actual service file name /ImageService.svc/UploadImages/....After I did this,I started getting 500 errors,with only an "internal error" description.I can't even get my breakpoints to hit in the service.I attached to the worker process that's running hosting the service in IIS,and nothing.So I'm shooting blanks and have no where else to turn.I've included the web.config at the <system.serviceModel> level under my original question.

Comment: Try enabling tracing on the server, it will give you the exception which is causing it to reply with a 404 or a 500.

Comment: Turns out it's the same message regarding the Steam object.                                                                                                                                                                          The exception message is: For request in operation UploadImages to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: For request in operation UploadMedia to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream.

Comment: I noticed in your web.config that the endpoint definition specifies the `webHttpBinding`, but it does not have a behaviorConfiguration which points to an endpoint behavior with the `<webHttp/>` element. In order to create a REST endpoint, you need **both** the webHttpBinding *and* the <webHttp/> behavior. Can you check that this is your issue?

Comment: I updated the Web.config with your recommendations & thought I correctly added the necessary elements & references for the querystringconverter to work.So I'm one step further,where I'm now receiving:                                                                    Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'MyQueryStringConverter'..---> System.InvalidOperationException:Operation 'UploadImages' in contract 'IImageService' has a query variable named 'tags' of type 'System.String[]', but type 'System.String[]' is not convertible by 'MyQueryStringConverter'.

Comment: Looks like I need to create a ServiceFactory, since there's a bug in the WebServiceHost: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/616486/bug-with-getquerystringconverter-not-being-called-by-webservicehost#details